# Can tex4ht support square justified text with different line spacings?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, tex4ht, html

Can `tex4ht` support square justified text and can I specify different line spacings (1, 1.15, 1.5, 2 etc.)?

`Sloppypar` allows me to square justify my paragraphs in a pdf but the html file in a web browser doesn't reflect this.  Similarly `\onehalfspacing` doesn't have any effect.

If I edit the pdf in MS word and change line spacing and square justification, the html document displayed in a browser reflects this desired appearance.  So I am hoping there is an environment option that can emulate these settings typset by `tex4ht`.

No MWE because I don't have any packages or macros in mind to try.

Comment: note justification is the default, sloppypar just tells latex to lower its normal standards and allow space to over-stretch to help with difficult content.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Interesting.  My documents are filled with such huge words I barely noticed anything except overfull lines inconsistently spilling into my margins.  Thanks for your comment, always great to learn about Tex defaults!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tex4ht` doesn't set alignment for normal text, it leaves default values, which is raggedright. You can easily provide justification for text with `\Css` command in the custom config file:

```
\Css{text-align:justify;}
```

because web browsers aren't TeX, they are really bad at justification and you will often see really big spaces between words. You can fix this issue if you enable hyphenation, which is only recent feature of the `CSS`. To enable hyphenation, you must declare document language, which isn't done by `tex4ht` by default, but you can configure that in the `.cfg` file again.

Sample `sample.cfg` file may look like this:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{body{text-align:justify;width:15em;margin:0 auto;}}
\Css{p{-webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
hyphens:auto;}}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
 lang="en">\Hnewline}}{\HCode{</html>}}{}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

now we may take a look look at particular declarations:

```
\Css{body{text-align:justify;width:15em;margin:0 auto;}}
```

this set text to be justified, width is only 15em, which is only to show the hyphenation, you should use bigger value, about 40em. `margin: 0 auto` horizontally center the text.

```
\Css{p{-webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
 hyphens:auto;}}
```

because hyphenation is recent `CSS3` feature, you need to use browser prefixes to enable it in all supported browsers.

```
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
 lang="en">\Hnewline}}{\HCode{</html>}}
```

this configures `<html>` element to include `lang="en"` attribute, this is needed to enable hyphenation. Of course use different shortcut if the document language is other than English.

The second issue is line spacing. With `tex4ht`, newer use switching commands like `onehalfspacing`, because this can't be configured to produce correct html tags. Always use environments for that. Simple example:

```
\ProvidesPackage{myspacing}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\newenvironment{onehalf}{\onehalfspacing}{}

\endinput
```

save it as `myspacing.sty`. now we must provide configuration for `tex4ht` in `myspacing.4ht`:

```
\ConfigureEnv{onehalf}{%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi \EndP\HCode{<div class="onehalf">}\par}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi \EndP\HCode{</div>}\par}
{}{}
\Css{.onehalf{line-height:150\%;}}
```

these `\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi \EndP` are here for correct paragraph handling, important is `\HCode{<div class="onehalf">}` which will produce `<div>` element with class `onehalf`, which is then configured using `css` to have 1.5 spacing.

We can test our configuration with some simple document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{myspacing}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{onehalf}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{onehalf}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

compile it with

```
htlatex filename sample
```

and the result:

[image]

(note that `lang="la"` was used in that example, as lipsum is latin text)